# How can I write a lambda statement that is a void Function

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following block of code in java that is creating and mutating data. I want it to be void instead of returning the start time variable. is there a way to do this with the lambda?

```
BiFunction<String, User, Long> closeTokenFunc = (tokenId, user) -> {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

         
            TokenList tokenList = issuanceManager.searchAssociatedToken(tokenId, user);
            List<String> associatedInstruments =
                    tokenList.getTokens().stream().map(token -> token.getTokenNumber()).collect(Collectors.toList());

           
            List<BatchRequestItem<TspBatchItemData>> items = createdTspBatch.getItems();
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < associatedInstruments.size() && j < items.size(); i++, j++) {
                BatchRequestItem<TspBatchItemData> item = items.get(j);
                item.getItemDetails().setEnrollmentId(associatedInstruments.get(i));
                item.save();
                batchItemIdsToValidate.add(item.getId());

                
                if (i == associatedInstruments.size() - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }

          
            try {
                queryHelper.updateInstrumentState(tokenId, "PENDING_ACTIVE");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Assert.fail("Exception - thrown - " + e.getMessage());
            }

            
            issuanceManager.closeToken(tokenId, TokenCloseRequest.TokenClosureReason.CLOSED, user);

            return startTime;
        };
```

I tried removing the BiFunction syntax but the functions such as closeToken(), will have a compile error because the tokenID variable should be a string, and without the BiFunction deceleration the variable is of type lambda.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) instead of [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).

According to the documentation for the `BiConsumer` functional interface:

> Represents an operation that accepts two input arguments and returns no result. This is the two-arity specialization of Consumer. Unlike most other functional interfaces, BiConsumer is expected to operate via side-effects.

```java
BiConsumer<String, User> closeTokenFunc = (tokenId, user) -> {
    // ...
};
// Usage example:
closeTokenFunc.accept("token id", new User());
```